# Entity Framework creating database with no tables in it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC web application. I've installed the Entity Framework.
I have done the following model:

```
public class EmploymentHistory
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public int DateFromMonth { get; set; }
    public int DateFromYear { get; set; }
    public int DateToMonth { get; set; }
    public int DateToYear { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("I was unemployed during this time")]
    public bool IsUnemployed { get; set; }
}
```

I have created the following DbContext class:

```
public class EmploymentDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EmploymentHistory> EmploymentsHistory { get; set; }
}
```

And the connection string in my Web.config file looks like that:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EmploymentDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=EmploymentsHistory;Integrated Security=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

When I run the project, I can see the database `EmploymentsHistory` in the Server Explorer in Visual Studio but when I expand it and then expand its Tables, I can't see the `EmploymentHistory` table which I'm supposed to see.

Comment: What happens when you try to add new object and saving it in database?

Comment: Add a `AttachDbFileName` path. It's always the same trouble with these localdb's. No doubt you're looking at the wrong database file.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a constructor to your `EmploymentDbContext` class, so it would be like this:

```
public class EmploymentDbContext : DbContext
{
    // constructor, which will also call DbContext's (base) constructor
    public EmploymentDbContext() : base("name=EmploymentDbContext") { } 

    public DbSet<EmploymentHistory> EmploymentsHistory { get; set; }
}
```

By calling `DbContext`'s constructor, you're specifying the name of the connection string you'd like this subclass of `DbContext` to attach to.

Edit:

Since you don't seem to be trying to use this connection anywhere currently, try explicitly adding a code-first migration. If you haven't already, run `enable-migrations` in your Package Manager Console. Close out of the Configuration screen it presents, and then run `add-migration EmploymentHistory`. Wait until it's finished, then run `update-database` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Is an exception being thrown, or is it simply not showing up?

Comment: Simply not showing up. There is the Table direcotry and the other directories StoredProcedures , Functions.. But in the Table directory - nothing.